# How to modify index.html file in build folder before sending it on each request with Nginx server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, facebook-opengraph, server-side-rendering

I want to modify the React's index.html file in the server before sending it to the browser on request. Reason is that, I want to include open graph meta tags into the head according to the request url. How can I achieve that with Nginx server ?

Comment: Check nginx [`sub_filter`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) module.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of options here.

### Use NGINX subs module

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

`sub_filter '<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/'  '<a href="https://$host/';`

### Use NGINX njs

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_js_module.html#js_body_filter

You can use njs and js_body_filter to filter the response body. Personally, I would use the njs way as you are more flexible in adding / changing data.

Make sure you are loading the ngx_http_js_module in your main nginx.conf file.